# Ajustes Margens e Cabeçalho

Tags: latex

Estou escrevendo minha dissertação da UFSC usando um template latex ufscthesis no overleaf.

Estou com dificuldade para ajustar as margens do documento.

Os parâmetros para definição das margens são:

> `\RequirePackage[a5paper,inner=2.5cm,outer=1.5cm,top=2.0cm,bottom=1.5cm,head=0.7cm,foot=0.7cm]{geometry}`

Se eu ajusto o valor em top a numeração da página fica desconfigurada pois move-se pra cima ou pra baixo.

Preciso que a margem superior seja 2cm, incluindo a numeração da página.

Já tentei remover o parametro head, já tentei incluir o parametro includehead mas nada se ajusta.

Alguma idéia?

Versão do template:

```
% Definicao do arquivo de classe UFSCThesis - Modelo de Tese para a BU-UFSC
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Versăo 20100631 - Baseada na classe ABNTex versăo 0.8-2
%                                                           
% (c)2010 Roberto Simoni (roberto.emc@gmail.com)
%         Carlos R Rocha (cticarlo@gmail.com)
```